# jquery show tooltip in function

Tags: jquery, html

I have some JQuery code to add a class and title to a HTML element:

```
emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect").attr('title', 'This field is required');
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zy8mz05L/2/)

The tooltip shows on element hover but how can I make it show as a tool tip and not just on hover?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - isn't the definition of a tooltip text that shows on hover?

Comment: yeah thats right but i though it displayed all the time and not just on hover? i could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need jQuery UI to make tooltips.

Another alternative could be [Boostrap tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).